# Session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My current Browser version in 83.0.4103.61. I have updated Chrome driver to 83.0.4103.3900 from NuGet Package Manager.  Getting error "Session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81" even after updating driver.  I am using Selenium WebDriver using C#. 
Note: It works fine for new solutions.

Comment: Seems you still have chromedriver 81. make sure you did necessary cleanup

Comment: I rebuild the solution after updating chrome driver. But getting error    Could not copy "D:\Source\SampleConsoleApp1\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.83.0.4103.3900\build\..\driver\win32\chromedriver.exe" to "D:\Source\SampleConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "chromedriver (9008), chromedriver (23396), chromedriver (23780), chromedriver (9316), chromedriver (24304), chromedriver (16708), chromedriver (10340), chromedriver (9292)

Comment: first kill all chromedriver processes using task manager or possible restart the system and then retry

Comment: Solved..                                                                                                                           
 1. Launch command prompt and enter "taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe"
 2. Clean your solution

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be your machine does not have the latest chrome browser. 
Either update the chrome browser or downgrade the chromedriver to 81.x.

Comment: My chrome browser version is 83 and I have updated chrome driver to 83.